# Grep with conditional context

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

I'd like to `grep` a file for a regex MR (main) and get all consecutive preceding lines that match a regex BR (before), and all consecutive following lines that match a regex AR (after).

i.e. something like this

```
grep -B [BR] -A [AR] [MR] file
```

e.g. for the following segment (taken from the [CHILDES](http://childes.psy.cmu.edu/) project):

```
8|10|SUBJ 9|10|AUX 10|6|ROOT 11|10|PUNCT
*CHI:   here .
%mor:   adv|here .
%gra:   1|0|INCROOT 2|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her (.) okay ?
%mor:   v|ask pro:poss:det|her adj|okay ?
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|3|MOD 3|1|OBJ 4|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her what she can eat .
%mor:   v|ask pro:obj|her pro:wh|what pro:sub|she mod|can v|eat .
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|1|OBJ 3|6|LINK 4|6|SUBJ 5|6|AUX 6|1|COMP 7|1|PUNCT
*URS:   but what is it ?
%mor:   conj|but pro:wh|what aux|be&3S pro|it ?
%gra:   1|3|LINK 2|3|OBJ 3|0|ROOT 4|3|OBJ 5|3|PUNCT
*CHI:   it's peaches and pears .
```

The query

```
grep -B '^\*' -A '^%' '^%mor:\s+v' file
```

will return

```
*URS:   ask her (.) okay ?
%mor:   v|ask pro:poss:det|her adj|okay ?
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|3|MOD 3|1|OBJ 4|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her what she can eat .
%mor:   v|ask pro:obj|her pro:wh|what pro:sub|she mod|can v|eat .
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|1|OBJ 3|6|LINK 4|6|SUBJ 5|6|AUX 6|1|COMP 7|1|PUNCT
```

In other words, I'm looking for all utterances (lines starting with *) that begin with a verb, and each utterance should be followed by its dependent tiers (lines starting with %). Feel free to suggest other command-line tools instead of grep (e.g. awk).

Another example, the query

```
grep -B '^[*%][gU]' -A '^%' '^%mor:\s+v' file
```

should return

```
%gra:   1|0|INCROOT 2|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her (.) okay ?
%mor:   v|ask pro:poss:det|her adj|okay ?
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|3|MOD 3|1|OBJ 4|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her what she can eat .
%mor:   v|ask pro:obj|her pro:wh|what pro:sub|she mod|can v|eat .
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|1|OBJ 3|6|LINK 4|6|SUBJ 5|6|AUX 6|1|COMP 7|1|PUNCT
```

Comment: I would use `awk` for this task. `awk` can maintain its own state and remember processed data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -v br='^[*%][gU]' -v ar='^%' -v mr='^%mor:[[:blank:]]+v' '
p && $0 ~ ar {
   print data RS $0
   p=0
   data=""
   next
}
$0 ~ br {
   data = (data=="" ? $0 : data RS $0)
   next
}
$0 ~ mr {
   data = data RS $0
   p=1
   next
}
{
   data = ""
}' file


%gra:   1|0|INCROOT 2|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her (.) okay ?
%mor:   v|ask pro:poss:det|her adj|okay ?
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|3|MOD 3|1|OBJ 4|1|PUNCT
*URS:   ask her what she can eat .
%mor:   v|ask pro:obj|her pro:wh|what pro:sub|she mod|can v|eat .
%gra:   1|0|ROOT 2|1|OBJ 3|6|LINK 4|6|SUBJ 5|6|AUX 6|1|COMP 7|1|PUNCT
```

This awk works as follows:

- When it matches `br` in a line it initiates a variable `data` with that line i.e. `data=$0`
- When it matches `mr` it appends that line in `data` variable and sets a flag `p=1`
- Finally when it matches `ar` it prints the data and current line if flag is set. Finally it reinitializes the flags.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate?

Comment: Added explanation in answer

Comment: In my example, `br` matched only a single line before `mr`. However, if `data` is initialized each time `br` is matched, what happens if `br` matches several lines?

Comment: Please see the edited question, I've added an example to illustrate this.

Comment: Try: `awk -v br='^[*%][gU]' -v ar='^%' -v mr='^%mor:[[:blank:]]+v' 'p && $0 ~ ar{print data RS $0; p=0; data=""; next} $0 ~ br{data = (data=="" ? $0 : data RS $0); next} $0 ~ mr{data = data RS $0; p=1; next} {data=""}' file`

Comment: Works, thanks a lot! Could you just update the explanation?